# Symfony2 routing domain virtual host

Tags: php, apache, symfony, routes

I haven't found any solution to my problem with symfony and virtual hosts.

I have one website **www.example.com** and have routes that have different contents based on an id.
Example:

www.example.com/id/1 is one website with menus that point to subpages:
www.example.com/id/1/page1

www.example.com/id/1/page2

www.example.com/id/1/page3

what I want is to set a new domain that points to this website with id 1 and another domain that points to id 2, etc.

For example:

**www.newdomain.com** shows content from www.example/id/1
**www.newdomain.com/page1** shows content from www.example/id/1/page1
**www.newdomain.com/page2** shows content from www.example/id/1/page2

**www.differentdomain.com** shows content from www.example/id/2
**www.differentdomain.com/page1** shows content from www.example/id/2/page1
...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you just have to point both virtual host configurations to the same folder to make both URLs work.

But the virtual host setting is just one side of the configuration. You won't be able to configure the actual behaviour of the application regarding the different incoming URLs. I don't know if this can also be achieved via .htaccess settings, but you can definitely check in the controller of your application from what URL the request was send and then forward the user accordingly.